# How to exclude formatting of text when dealing with numbers? Django

Tags: django

In my template I'm outputting various numbers which range in the millions.

I'm using Humanize function to format the numbers.

```
{% load humanize %}

.....

{{ aircraft.maximum_range|floatformat|intcomma }}
```

On my comparison page I have the following code which returns all of the numerical attributes. I could use `|floatformat|intcomma` to format the numbers but I'm also returning the title of the post also in the variable of `Value`. Can I do an if statement which states for the text not to be formatted?

```
  {% for value in row %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
    <th>{{ value }}</th>
    {% else %}
    <td class="text-center"><strong>{{ value }}</strong></td>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

By doing `{{ value|floatformat|intcomma }}` the title isnt included but I need it there. How do I solve this?

EDIT:

The first value in the code above are the titles of the categories: range, cost, engines etc. The second value are the actual numbers. As you can see in the picture, the name of the aircraft next to "Aircraft" is not being shown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqv4j.jpg)

Comment: can you provide an example value of the variable "value"?

Comment: Check the image link in the edits

Comment: Did you try with a custom template tag or filter? Look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags